# How to capture dropdown selection into a view for conversion to excel

Tags: python, django, view

Hello fellow learned friends. I'd like to add a filter to a model query from a dropdown selection before converting the results to excel for download. I can't get it right since I don't know how to capture the dropdown selected item into the view.
How do I get it working??

```
def convert_to_excel(file_name, columns, values):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.xls"'.format(file_name)

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet(file_name.capitalize())

    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)
    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    for row in values:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
    wb.save(response)
    return response


def archive_to_excel(request):
    mark_list = Marks.objects.filter(school=request.user.school).annotate(total = \
     F("eng") + F("kis") + F("mat") + F("che") + F("phy") + F("bio") + F("cre")+ F("ire")+ \
     F("hre") + F("geo") + F("his") + F("agr") + F("hsc") + F("bst")+ F("mus")+ F("ger")+ F("fre"))\
    .order_by('-total').annotate(mean = F('total')/15).values_list('student__name',\
        'student__adm', 'student__form__name', 'student__stream__name', 'student__kcpe','eng','kis','mat','che','phy','bio','cre','ire','hre','geo',\
        'his','agr','total','mean').order_by('-id')

    columns = [('name'), ('adm'),('form'),('stream'), ('kcpe'), ('eng'), ('kis'), ('mat'), ('che'), ('phy'), ('bio'), ('cre'),\
     ('ire'), ('hre'), ('geo'), ('his'), ('agr'),('total'),('mean') ]

    return convert_to_excel("Marks", columns, mark_list)
```